# React-native-payments: issue Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: android, ios, react-native, payment

It's about the react-native-payments from Naoufal
I follow the simple tutorial, all is good, installation, setting, and so on.

When I called paymentRequest.show(). I have the warning

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection(id:0)

I've already write a message to the developer, maybe the issue is in its side, I don't know.

Here is the simple code:

```
        const METHOD_DATA = [{
            supportedMethods: ['android-pay'],
            data: {
                supportedNetworks: ['visa', 'mastercard', 'amex'],
                currencyCode: 'USD',
                environment: 'TEST', // defaults to production
                paymentMethodTokenizationParameters: {
                    tokenizationType: 'NETWORK_TOKEN',
                    parameters: {
                        publicKey: 'your-public-key'
                    }
                }
            }
        }];

        const DETAILS = {
            id: 'basic-example',
            displayItems: [
                {
                    label: 'Movie Ticket',
                    amount: { currency: 'USD', value: '15.00' }
                }
            ],
            total: {
                label: 'Merchant Name',
                amount: { currency: 'USD', value: '15.00' }
            }
        };

        const paymentRequest = new PaymentRequest(METHOD_DATA, DETAILS);

        paymentRequest.show().then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        });
```

I just want to display the payment view. 
Here is the link of tutorial:
https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments

Comment: Add a `catch` to the method an see the complete error. `paymentRequest.show().then((response) => { console.log(response) }).catch((error) => console.log(error));`

Comment: @bennygenel Just tried it, have exactly the same warning. No error

Comment: Please add the complete warning/error message to your question.

Comment: @bennygenel "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
10"

Comment: @bennygenel Here, another guy has the same issue: https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments/issues/28

Comment: then it may be related to package itself

Comment: @bennygenel Yeah, I think too

Comment: Any updates on this? How did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Guys, I'm also getting the same issues. if anyone done this. Please update here